# how to do text wrapping for long text in text view on android

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

In my application,i have text view with long text. i need text wrapping like in the android emulator->contact->phone (screen short of dialpad in contact).

[image]

but in my application i get text wrapping as follows in the figure:
[image]

i have tried several ways it does not meet my requirement.
 i do not need the "..." at right corner of the text view. instead of that, i want to wrap the text as in the first figure(android emulator->contact->phone). how to do that? please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this Dialer example maybe helpful :[Simple Dialer Application](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/simpleDialer.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think setting the following properties to your **TextView** should help you to achieve this behavior:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="none"
android:singleLine="false"
```

Comment: How to apply these for dynamically-created textviews?

Comment: singleLine is deprecated because its default value is false

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use support library's autosizing for `TextViews` as per [the Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview).

**How to use?**

For API 26 and later:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

To support earlier version of Android you can use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

If you have an option that increases/decreases `TextView` size then you can do:

For API 26 and later:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp" />
```

For earlier versions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
      app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
      app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
      app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp" />
```

Comment: Why down vote my answer? If its not helping then you may edit instead!

Comment: your answer is exactly the same for API 26+ and earlier versions.

Comment: @Errol, Its not the same. Please check the attribute "app:..." for earlier versions and "android:..." for API 26 and later. I tested both and worked!

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio 3.5

All you need to do is set an End constraint in a constraintlayout inside your textView:

`app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`